# How do I recover data off a laptop that has died?

Tags: hard-drive, laptop, data-recovery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Recovering files from laptop with XP that won't boot](https://superuser.com/questions/78874/recovering-files-from-laptop-with-xp-that-wont-boot)
>   [Need to recover data from laptop before sending it in for repair](https://superuser.com/questions/252318/need-to-recover-data-from-laptop-before-sending-it-in-for-repair)

My Samsung laptop running Windows Vista has died. How do I recover the data that was on it? It will not turn on – is there any way I can get the data off the hard drive?

Maybe by using some sort of adapter?

I'm now running Mac with OS X Lion if that makes it any difference for recovering, although I also have a Windows laptop I can get my hands on too.

Comment: See also: [Recovering files from laptop with XP that won't boot](http://superuser.com/questions/78874/recovering-files-from-laptop-with-xp-that-wont-boot) — basically, put its hard drive into another computer.

Answer (score 2):

> Maybe by using some sort of adapter?

Yes, you can remove the hard drive from one computer and either:

- temporarily install it as an extra drive internally in another computer.
- buy an **IDE/SATA to USB adapter** and connect it externally to another computer.

[image: example SATA to USB external adapter]

This example has these features

- Connect your IDE or SATA hard drives externally via a USB port
- Allows you to connect 2.5-inch, 3.5-inch IDE and SATA hard drives
- Includes 3.5-inch to 2.5-inch adaptor, SATA power and data cables
- Complete with Power Adaptor
- Compliant with USB 2.0 transfer
- 'Plug 'n' Play'

Check they have the right type of connectors, SATA connectors can be included but separate.

Comment: Is this the right one? http://www.amazon.co.uk/IOMAX-SATA-Adapter-Power-Drive/dp/B001A5SK56 and would you say its the right sort of cost or can you get it cheaper?

Comment: @HenryHoggard: The Superuser [FAQ](http://superuser.com/faq) rules out shopping advice, but yes that looks OK to me (I used one from Maplin).

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "it will not turn on"? Do you get to see the BIOS screen? If yes, then you could you use [Parted Magic](http://partedmagic.com/doku.php) to boot up the laptop and get to your hard drive. You can boot Parted Magic either (a) by burning CD/DVD or (b) by creating bootable USB flash drive using [UNetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/).

EDIT: You said you have an access to another laptop, so either replace its hard drive, boot using lice CD/flash drive and get your data OR  you could get one of these [USB](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B002JQNXZC) / [eSATA](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B002XW0KYO) enclosure.

Comment: No power will go to it at all, so live cd is out of the question.